# Find substring in a string with parsec

Tags: haskell, parsec

For example, I want to get `"abc"` from `"aabbccabc"`, which should be easy with regex. But i want to use parsec. It seems that `try` can do that, but that must be quite inefficient...

I tried:

```hs
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec
ps pser txt = case (parse pser  "" txt ) of
  Left e  -> show e
  Right v -> v
```

and got the following result:

```hs
λ> ps (string "asf") "  dsfdsasf"
"(line 1, column 1):\nunexpected \" \"\nexpecting \"asf\""
```

Comment: *[...] I want to get `"abc"` from `"aabbccabc"` [...]* What do you mean, exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.Char

findSubString str = try (string str) <|> (anyChar *> findSubString str)

foo = do
  findSubString "abc"
  findSubString "def"

test1 = parseTest foo "this is abc"         -- fails: expecting def

test2 = parseTest foo "this is abc and de"  -- fails: expecting def

test3 = parseTest foo "this is abc and def" -- succeeds
```

Comment: that works,but uses try ,which utilize backtracking. With large file will this be inefficent?

Comment: I think you should explain why you want to use parsec to search for a string in a large file. Why parsec? Why not just `breakOn` from `Data.Text`?

Comment: Because i may extend the parsing work to more complicated one,breakOn is a good suggestion